# iOS Swift design for integrating n/w layer

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I have simple ListView that needs to display the records from the network layer. (first screen of the application)

I need to get some opinion as to which will be correct flow so that I can make the unit test cases easily. (No VIPER architecture)

NetworkMgr makes the network calls and create Model objects.

These Model objects needs to be populated in ListTableView.

I have a completion handler method to call the network request which give the model objects.

```
func getData() {
 dataMgr.requestData(url:  "String") { (EmployeesArray, error) in

        //  print(error)
    }
}
```

Now the Question is - For unit testing when I am calling the ListDataTest since the ListVC is in storyboard when it loads the View the viewdidLoad method calls the which will initiate the network logic.

SO I am not able to test only the UI related stuffs.

I tried to create some extension in ListDataTest class but no success is achieved.

Below is the flow of the Controllers : -

===

```
class ListVC: UIViewController {

 var dataProvider: ListData

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataProvider.viewLoaded()
  }
}
```

=======
In ListData class

```
protocol DatProviderLoad {

func viewLoaded()
}

class ListData: NSObject {


}

extension ListData : DatProviderLoad {

func viewLoaded() {
    print("loaded")
  //the network calls goes here
   }
}
```

/—
The test class

```
class ListDataProviderTest: XCTestCase {

var sut: ListData!
var controller: ListVC!
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    sut = ListData()
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
    controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListVC") as! ListVC
   controller.dataProvider = sut //before this called the storyboard already called the viewdidload once
    _ = controller.view 
   }
}
```

Your feedback will be very helpful.

Any hint or tutorial in right direction will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try to do this in `MVVM` way.

Think ViewController as part of View layer. 
To call the network layer and to convert models into view models introduce a ViewManager.

The Viewcontroller will ask ViewManager to provide the data(ViewModel) and passes all actions(like button press) to ViewManager to handle the business logic.

This way it will be easy to write test cases for ViewManager layer(which is supposed to have all the business logic) and your View is not coupled with either the Network layer or data models.

Comment: So if ViewMgr have getData method. So when the app. starts  who initiates the getData call. I assume the ViewMgr refr. should be present in ViewCtr.

Comment: @Ekra: The preferred way is to create a protocol and ViewController will have reference to the object conforming the protocol. This way you abstract the ViewManager class but yes you are right the ViewController will have reference and will tell ViewManager class that the view is loaded. The ViewManager after knowing this, can initiate the network fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have updated my question please have a look into it

Comment: @Ekra: The view does not get load i.e. viewDidLoad does not get called on instantiateViewController method. It should not happen in your case as well. The view gets loaded on accessing controller.view. I dont think there is anything wrong with your code.